# How to filter by category in FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

As you can see [here](https://graph.facebook.com/175004205872488),

Businesses have their category information: Local Business, Sport, Education.. etc. It is the field "category".

I would like to know, is there a way to filter businesses by their category and position with FQL? I haven't found how to do it. For instance: give me all the sports center in this circle (lat, lon, radius).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for something and haven't found anything. It appears that only the graph api has the category information for a page.

Comment: I opened a bug, i think it is accepted: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14935

Answer (score 6):

The "category" attribute in the "page" table is called "type". Here is a query to filter the logged-in user's "local business" likes:

SELECT page_id, name, description, type, pic, fan_count

FROM page

WHERE 

   page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me())

   AND Type = 'LOCAL BUSINESS'

[Run Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20page_id,%20name,%20username,%20description,%20type,%20pic,%20pic_small,%20pic_large,%20pic_big,%20pic_square,%20pic_cover,%20fan_count,%20website%0AFROM%20page%20%0AWHERE%20page_id%20IN%20%28175004205872488%29%0A)

Answer (score 5):

You can't retrieve pages by category.

The FQL [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) table has a field called categories.

You can retrieve the category for a business with FQL like this:

```
SELECT categories FROM page WHERE page_id = PAGE_ID
```

where PAGE_ID is the page's Facebook id.

However, categories is not an indexable field. You can't ask for all business in New York which are Florists since "WHERE categories = florist" isn't allowed.